# Managing items in a scene QT

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am really in a pickle and I'm in desperate need of help. I am trying to collect some properties of items (instance of a QGraphicsitem subclass) in a QGraphicsScene subclass.  This code is in the DiagramItem class precisely in the double click event:

```
DiagramItem *cur;
QVector<QString> hal;
foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, this->scene()->items())
{
    cur = qgraphicsitem_cast<DiagramItem *>(item);
    hal.push_back(cur->getName());
}
```

Now it works fine when I have one item in my scene, but once I add another the app just crashes!
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall check the result of the cast:

```
cur = qgraphicsitem_cast<DiagramItem *>(item);
if ( cur )
{
    hal.push_back(cur->getName());
}
```

Maybe there are other items in your scene, which cannot be casted to `DiagramItem` object.

Comment: You're welcome. Never forget to check the result of any cast.